# Usage of '.' inside `include directive

Tags: system-verilog

I've come across some code that does something like:

```
`include "./some_path/some_file.svh"
```

Is this equivalent to:

```
`include "some_path/some_file.svh"
```

?

The LRM states that relative paths are considered as starting from either the compiler's current working directory or from user specified locations, so I would expect '.' to be substitutable for any of these paths.

I'm guessing the intention was to specify a path that is relative to the including file's location and someone didn't really understand what they were doing.

Comment: Not a specification answer, but if you want to see how _your_ compiler is resolving that file name, you could start the compile with `strace -f -o strace.log [rest of the compile command or top level script/makefile/whatever command ... ]`  After the compile runs, you can grep `strace.log` for `some_path/some_file.svh`.  Running strace will make the compile take a lot longer.  You'll see file open system commands that show the compiler's internal mechanism. Anyways, not an LRM answer, but may be useful in dealing with your specific compiler.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be OS dependent and not part of the SystemVerilog LRM. ./ usually means search the current working directory only and not the reast of the search path.

Comment: The second part, regarding searching from the including file location is, I would assume, impossible, right?

Comment: I'm not sure. There might be a tool specific way of getting this behavior.